# Dependency management by external tools versus IDE sugar

Tags: intellij-idea, dependencies, ivy, dependency-management

I'm using Intellij IDEA IDE. Instead of using it's internal build and dependency management tools I prefer external tools (ant+ivy if it matters). I want IDEA be able somehow catch on the flylibraries that were retrieved by dependency manager, index them and obviously provide ide sugar (code suggesting and so on).

Is there plugin or any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Ivy, but it already works like this with Maven. You should take a look at "IvyIDEA"; its description says.

> Detect source/document/jar type ivy artifacts in dependencies and add them as such to the module